# Merge attribute table with conditional statements in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, expression

I have two attribute tables with different values in QGIS.

The merge value between both tables is an ID number, each of this ID number have more than one values related with crops and area in the second table (imagine an id number for a polygon and each polygon have for example 4 values by crop and area)

My idea is to choose only one crop by the maximum area for every ID number, I need a conditional expression for that but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: You have two tables with no geometries?

Comment: Yes, is just data, no geometries

Comment: you can use the aggregate function for that. Please provide more information on your table structure, then we can provide an example expression